# Float, Double, and Exponential Output in C

Tags: c, cygwin

Here's my code:

```
void main()
{
    printf("%s\n", "Hello World!");
    printf("%c\n",'a');
    printf("%d\n", 'a');
    printf("%d\n",10);
    printf("%d\n", -10);
    printf("%lf\n", 3.14159265);
    printf("%d\n", 3.14159265);
    printf("%e\n", 314159265);
}
```

My output is this:

```
Hello World!
a
97
10
-10
3.141593
1405670641
1.552153e-315
```

My question is three fold:

If double holds 16 digits, why is the output showing 7 significant digits?

Why is the exponential number showing a completely different number, possibly a garbage value?

Furthermore when I changed the code to this: `printf("%lf\n", 3);`. It shows output as `0.000000`. Why so?

Comment: The default precision [in `printf` et. al.] is 6 fractional digits (e.g.) `%.6f` . If you want more, do (e.g.) `%.9f` Likewise for `%e`

Comment: What makes you think a double holds 16 digits?

Comment: What is the value of the bits "11010011"?  You can only answer that question if you know the format.  If you tell the system that it is an int but you want the bits interpreted as a float, you will get a "wrong" answer.  You lie when you give a format string of `%e` if you expect the system to interpret the bits as an integer.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The table at http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~rookert/cs162/ecampus-video/CS161/template/chapter_2/datatypes.html says so.

Comment: Add the `-Wall -Wextra`options to you C/C++ command line. E.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O0 -o code.exe code.c`

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main()`  Regardless of what some compilers will let you 'get away with', there are only two valid signatures for `main()`.  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: @user3629249 Can you provide some explanation or some web article that expands on this?

Comment: @Debol, the valid signatures for `main()` are specifically spelled out in the C programming standard

Comment: @Debol, from the standard:  N1570 Committee Draft — April 12, 2011ISO/IEC 9899:201x5.1.2.2.1  Program  startup1The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype  for  this  function.   It  shall  be  defined  with  a  return  type  of int and  with  no parameters:int main(void) { /*...*/ }or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ } or equivalent; 10)or in some other implementation-defined manner*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    printf("%d\n", 3.14159265);  // a)
    printf("%e\n", 314159265);   // b)
```

a) The conversion specifier `"%d"` expects a `int` value; the value `3.14159265` has type `double`. Try `printf("%f", 3.14159265);` or `printf("%d", 3);`

b) The conversion specifier `"%e"` expects a `double` value; the value `314159265` has type `int`. Try `printf("%d", 314159265);` or `printf("%f", 3.1415926);`

Mismatching the conversion specifier and the associated value invokes Undefined Behaviour.

---

To print a specific number of decimals use the `"%.nf"` specifier

```
printf("%.3f", 3.14159265);
printf("%.6f", 3.14159265);
printf("%.9f", 3.14159265);
```

The `printf()` specifier `"%lf"` is absolutely identical to `"%f"` (they are different for `scanf()`)

Comment: Can you edit your answer and explain me the outputs of ```printf("%lf\n", 3.14159265);``` and ```printf("%lf\n", 3);```. I'm expecting double to print 16 significant digits and the second is basically showing a possible garbage value.

Comment: `printf("%lf\n", 3);` has a mismatch between the specifier (`double`) and the value (`int`). Don't do that.